# How to calculate the average between two columns?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to calculate the average of the values in another column, e. g. values, in the database from ID 24 to ID 4? So the 20 daily average from ID 24 to ID 4.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please read [ask], and consider providing a [mre] (or, for your SQL question, try [tips for asking a good SQL question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question)).

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
SELECT AVG(stand)
FROM youtable
WHERE id BETWEEN 4 AND 24;
```

You select only the rows where the id is between 4 and 24, then you calculate the average on the stand column. Documentation [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html#function_avg)

Comment: @Luis There's no column "date" or symbol in your example. Please update the question.